# Talend - tRESTClient --> tExtractJSONField - json path query

Tags: json, rest, etl, talend, jsonpath

I have this workflow in Talend:
[image]

I send a req to: https://api.coinbase.com/v2/currencies

And get this JSON responce:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "AED",
      "name": "United Arab Emirates Dirham",
      "min_size": "0.01000000"
    },
    {
      "id": "AFN",
      "name": "Afghan Afghani",
      "min_size": "0.01000000"
    },
    {
      "id": "ZWL",
      "name": "Zimbabwean Dollar",
      "min_size": "0.01000000"
    }
  ]
}
```

However tExtractJSONField does not parse the JSON.

I can not get the paths and options right.
Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

What are the right Jsonpath query and mapping table to extract all id's from JSON responce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Loop Jsonpath query, you need to use:

```
$.data[*]
```

And in the json query for each column, you put the corresponding field name: id, name, min_size.
[image]

[image]

Warning: tRESTClient has a setting to convert json to xml, which is enabled by default. You need to go to advanced settings and uncheck "convert response to DOM document".

Comment: Why does JSON field have the value newColumn, i have string,boby,statusCode?
Also how to do the maping, When i go to Edit schema on the left i have 
statusCode Integer
body Document
string String

I presume my json is in the string, but how to write the mapping when i want it on the right.

Comment: How does your edit schema window look like?
Can you add it to your post?

Comment: newColumn is the column name in my job because I didn't use tRestClient, but for you it's the column "string" that's in tRESTClient; In the tExtractJSONFields schema, you can set all the fields you want from the json; in my example I have id, name, min_size in the schema.

Comment: I was too lazy to use tRestClient, I just used your json in a file.
Now I updated my answer with screenshots using tRestClient.

Comment: [statistics] connected
.--+----+--------.
|   tLogRow_1    |
|=-+----+-------=|
|id|name|min_size|
|=-+----+-------=|
'--+----+--------'
it still says tExtractJSONFields_1 -- 0 rows in 2 seconds --> tLogRow_1.
Basic Settings of tExtractJSONFields_1 are identical to your (new) screenshot.

Comment: Can you add a tLogRow between tRestClient and tExtractJsonFields to check the API output?

Comment: The json lies in the body part, not the string part.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root><data><id>AED</id><name>United Arab Emirates Dirham</name><min_size>0.01000000</min_size></data><data><id>AFN</id><name>Afghan Afghani</name><min_size>0.01000000</min_size></data><data><id>ALL</id><name>Albanian Lek</name><min_size>0.01000000</min_size></data><data><id>AMD</id><name>Armenian Dram</name><min_size>0.01000000</min_size>

Comment: But this now looks like xml, not json.
This confuses me, why in insomnia i get something that looks like json, and here i get xml. Now the parser says: Expected to find an object with property ['root'] in path $ but found 'java.lang.String'. This is not a json object according to the JsonProvider: 'com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.JsonSmartJsonProvider'.

Comment: Ok I see the problem, the tRestClient has a setting to convert json to xml, which is enabled by default. You need to go to advanced settings and uncheck "convert response to DOM document"

Comment: I ran into a new problem. Changed the API source, and the response is now in the body part, not the string part. It looks like this:
{
  "code": 200,
  "message": "Data fetched.",
  "response": [
    {
       "id": 1522,
    },
    {
      "id": 6924,
    },
    {
      "id": 51975,
    }
  ]
}
Loop JSON path query is now "$.responce[*]", i tried changing the mapping type to Document/String, but it does not find the id element. Is there anything else to try with the JSON parser?